# How to perform realtime query and show data in autocomplete

Tags: jquery, mysql, autocomplete

My index.html file

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Demo</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.1/themes/base/minified/jquery-ui.min.css" type="text/css" /> 
</head>
<body> 

<form action='' method='post'>
    <p><label>Country:</label><input type='text' name='country' value='' class='auto'></p>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js">     </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>    
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {

//autocomplete
$(".auto").autocomplete({
    source: "search.php",
    minLength: 1
});             

});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

My search.php file

```
<?php

$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","something","hindi_test");

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
mysqli_set_charset ( $con , 'utf8' );

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT A FROM data ");

while($row = $result->fetch_object()){
        $user_arr[] = $row->A;


}
echo json_encode($user_arr);

mysqli_close($con);

?>
```

This code works fine. It shows all the data members of 'A' column. Now I want to show autocomplete on the basis user entering data, so that the data gets filtered on entering more character. How to do that in my search.php file ?

Comment: Please read following documentation to learn more about autocomplete widget.
http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote

Comment: I will take me hours to read it and I am new to jquery

Comment: This is how you will learn, if we write you working code then you will not learn well.

Comment: I don't have much time. At least give some hints

Comment: Read the answer posted by Callebe.
That's very helpful for you.

Answer (score 1):

According the [autocomplete jquery documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/)

> a query string is added with a term field, which the server-side script should use for filtering the results. For example, if the source option is set to "http://example.com" and the user types foo, a GET request would be made to http://example.com?term=foo

May you read the query string on server side and filter your query with de term value

Your query could be like that:

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT A FROM data WHERE A LIKE %". $_GET["term"] ."%");
```

off course you have to sanitise the $_GET["term"] to prevent SQL injection attack.

Comment: Used this $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT A FROM data WHERE A LIKE %".$_GET["term"]."% ");

It doesn't work.  Undefined index: term

Answer (score 0):

```
if(isset($_GET['term']))
{
    $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT A FROM data WHERE A LIKE %". $_GET["term"] ."%");
}
```